# Calculate Mode SQL Server - Single Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table

```
Accesses
90
83
43
33
33
33
53
532
64
743
743
23
```

I am trying to calculate the MODE from these values. There is no grouping column, the table consists of 100 different values, and I am trying to find the mode of these values (the most common value)..

Answer (score 1):

You can find the mode by using aggregation and `top`:

```
select top 1 Accesses
from t
group by Accesses
order by count(*) desc;
```

You can include `count(*)` in the `select` to get the count.  You can use `top (1) with ties` if you want all modes.

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 accesses
from your_table
group by accesses
order by count(*) desc
```